# Generating Gantt Charts for process scheduling

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pgfgantt

I am trying to create a gantt chart for my thesis on blocking analysis. I know of the `pgfgantt` package for generating gantt charts. But this package generates charts for normal schedules, what I need is gantt charts specifically for blocking analysis, like those used in Operating Systems text books.

Here is an example of what I need:

[image: Gantt Chart for CPU scheduling]

How can I make a chart similar to this one using pdflatex? I don't mind using pgfgantt either, except I don't see how it can render something like this.

Comment: It's not that hard to do it by hand with TikZ. However, if you're going to do a lot of them it could be tedious. Do you need a package like `pgfgantt` or you may give it a try to make it by hand?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @nico: My problem with pgfgantt is I couldn't find anything in the documentation which would allow diagrams with blocking, preemption, etc to be drawn. I may give it a try by hand using TikZ but as you say it will be tedious since I will have loads of such charts to draw.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Thanks! But my problem is that I have no MWE as of now. Unless I draw it by hand through TikZ, which would be too tedious. I haven't tried using pgfgantt since I couldn't find anything in the documentation which would lead me to believe that it can be done

Comment: It might be possible to adapt (with new styles, etc.) the functionality of [`tikz-timing`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) to accomplish this.

Comment: The package [`rtsched`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rtsched) can be used to create simple process scheduling diagrams, but I don't know if it is possible to do such a "complex" chart.
See the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/rtsched/rtsched-doc.pdf) for more details!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could not resist:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcounter{gridw}
\newcounter{procs}
\newif\ifinpgroup 
\inpgroupfalse

\newenvironment{schedulechart}[1]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=10,y=15,>=latex,
  processbox/.style={draw,fill=white},
  pendingbox/.style={fill=black!25},
  midstroke/.style={path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);}},
  divided/.style={path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.north west) -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}}]
 \setcounter{gridw}{#1}
 \setcounter{procs}{0}
 \def\gridw{\thegridw}
 \foreach\x in {0,...,\gridw}{
  \draw[black!25] ({\x+1},0) -- ++(0,1);
  \pgfmathparse{Mod(\x,5)==0?1:0};
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
   \draw ({\x+1},0) coordinate (c\x) -- ({\x+1},.5);
   \node at ([yshift=-5]c\x.south) {\x};
  \else
   \draw ({\x+1},0) coordinate (c\x) -- ({\x+1},.25);
  \fi
 }
}{%
 \draw[<->,>={Latex[open]}] (0,{\procs+1}) -- (0,0) -- ({\gridw+2},0);%
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
    
\newcommand{\process}[3][]{
 \stepcounter{procs}
 \def\procs{\theprocs}
 \draw[black!25] (0,\procs) coordinate (r\procs) -- ({\gridw+1},\procs);
 \foreach\x in {0,...,\gridw}
  \draw[black!25] ({\x+1},\procs) -- ++(0,1);
 \ifinpgroup\else
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
   \node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=5,xshift=-25]r\procs.west) {$#1$:};
  \fi
  \draw[black!25] (r\procs.west) -- ++(-5,0);
 \fi
 \node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=5,xshift=0]r\procs.west) {$#2$};
 \begin{scope}[yshift={\procs*15}]
  #3
 \end{scope};
}

\newcommand{\processstart}[2][]{
 \foreach\x/\y in {#2}
  \draw[processbox,#1] ({\x+1},0) coordinate (a) rectangle ({\y+1},.5);
 \draw[->] (a) -- ++(0,.9);
}

\newcommand{\processmid}[2][]{
 \foreach\x/\y in {#2}
  \draw[pendingbox,#1] ({\x+1},.1) rectangle ({\y+1},.4);
}

\newcommand{\processblock}[2][]{
 \foreach\x/\y in {#2}
  \draw[processbox,divided] ({\x+1},0) rectangle ({\y+1},.5) 
   node[anchor=north east,inner sep=1pt,xshift=1pt] {\tiny $#1$};
}

\newcommand{\processend}[2][]{
 \foreach\x/\y in {#2}
  \draw[processbox,#1] ({\x+1},0) rectangle ({\y+1},.5) coordinate (a);
 \draw[-|] (a) -- ++(0,.25);
}

\newenvironment{processgroup}[1]{
 \inpgrouptrue
 \def\procs{\theprocs}
 \draw[black!25] ([yshift=15]r\procs.west) coordinate (g0) -- ++(-5,0);
 \def\processgroupname{#1}
}{
 \path (g0) -- coordinate[midway] (m) (r\procs.west);
 \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] ([xshift=-22]g0) -- ([xshift=-22,yshift=10]r\procs.west);
 \node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=5,xshift=-25]m) {$\processgroupname$:};
 \inpgroupfalse
}

\begin{document}

\begin{schedulechart}{15}

\process[P_1]{J_1}{\processstart{1/3}\processmid[fill=none,midstroke]{3/10}\processend{10/12}}
\process[P_2]{J_2}{\processstart{0/2}\processmid[fill=none,midstroke]{2/7}\processend{7/9}}
\process[P_3]{J_3}{\processstart{0/1}\processmid[fill=none,midstroke]{1/4}\processend{4/7}}

\begin{processgroup}{P_4}
 \process{J_4}{\processstart{0/1}\processmid{1/10}\processend{10/13}}
 \process{A_1}{\processstart{2/2}\processmid{2/4}\processblock[J_2]{4/7}\processblock[J_1]{7/10}}
 \process{A_2}{\processstart{1/1}\processblock[J_3]{1/4}}
\end{processgroup}

\end{schedulechart}

\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: `\setcounter{procs}{0}` should be added to the beginning of the definition of the `schedulechart` environment

Comment: @MikeD. Good point! If you want to use the diagram mulitple times, this is essential, of course! Thank you! Added